# When user creation, assign role_id with UUID

Tags: laravel

I have a UUID system on my application and when I register a user I have to indicate the rank_id, only I don't know its ID as it is generated from a UUID.
So I use a query but it seems to me disgusting.

Do you have another solution?
I thought about not putting a UUID on the rank table to make it easier but I don't know if it's a good idea to mix uuid and classic id

```
User::create([
   'rank_id' => Rank::select('id')->where('title', 'User')->first()->id,
   'username' => $request->input('username'),
   'email' => strtolower($request->input('email')),
   'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
]);
```

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();

            $table->foreignUuid('rank_id')->constrained('ranks');

            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('status')->default(0);

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
Schema::create('ranks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();

            $table->string('title');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: could you please explain bit more

Comment: When I create an User, I need to specify the rank_id (admin or user..) but rank table have UUID and I can't know the id of the user rank, I need to make a query to get it

Comment: so user can have only one rank. right

Comment: yes, right belongsTo(user) and HasMany(rank)

Comment: rank belongsTo(User::class) user hasOne(Rank::class)

Comment: yes, but the problem is, how can I know the rank_id without make a query ? Is it possible to pass a single table with id and not uuid like everything else?

Comment: could you please show the data in rank table here

Comment: I just edited the post

Comment: are there are multiple users and admins in rank table ?

Comment: I'm having trouble explaining my problem, that's not the problem, it's how I indicate the rank of a new user.
Usually if the rank of the user was 1, I would have indicated 1, but here I don't know the id of the rank user, I have to make a query, I find it not clean in the code.

Comment: Mmmm bit just run the query outside of the create query. I dont see it as a bad way. But this should be more simple than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easier access, create a helper class or function and use it.

For example create a directory called `app\Helpers` and inside create a class called `RankHelper`. The implementation can be like below:

```php
namespace App\Helpers;

use App\Models\Rank;

class RankHelper
{
    public static function getIdByName(string $name): string
    {
        if (!$rank = Rank::select('id')->where('title', $name)->first()) {
            throw new \Exception("No rank with this name found.");
        }
        
        return $rank->id;
    }
}
```

Then inside your user creation logic just use it like:

```php
User::create([
   'rank_id'   => RankHelper::getIdByName('User'),
   'username'  => $request->input('username'),
   'email'     => strtolower($request->input('email')),
   'password'  => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! However, I would like to know if it is a common practice to do so?

Comment: @Kylian Since you are interacting with database, at some level you have to make query. At most you can use a cache like mechanism in the `RankHelper` class and prevent excessive db query, but at some point you have to make the query. Is this a common practice? I myself when I need some complicated db related stuff like this, I use it since it keeps my codes clean.

Comment: Great thanks a lot for your precious help! I used to specify an id directly here and found it "overkill" to query there directly. At least now I know it's done, thanks!

Comment: @Kylian Your welcome, Vote up and accept the answer if it helped you :)